# Build issues with Hadoop on windows

Tags: maven, hadoop

I am trying to build hadoop on windows and I am following this link http://opensourceforu.efytimes.com/2015/03/getting-started-with-hadoop-on-windows/. However when I try to build the code using the command 
***mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests Dtar*** 
I am getting the following error

```
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\SS\.m2\repository\org\s
onatype\plexus\plexus-cipher\1.4\_remote.repositories
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\SS\.m2\repository\org\s
onatype\plexus\plexus-cipher\1.4\plexus-cipher-1.4.jar.lastUpdated
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\SS\.m2\repository\org\a
pache\maven\plugin-tools\maven-plugin-annotations\3.4\_remote.repositories
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\SS\.m2\repository\org\a
pache\maven\plugin-tools\maven-plugin-annotations\3.4\maven-plugin-annotations-3
.4.jar.lastUpdated
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 25:08 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-21T17:02:06+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/173M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hadoop-maven-plugins: Could not resolv
e dependencies for project org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:maven-plugin:2
.7.2: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0 from/to c
entral (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/apache/maven/
maven-model/3.0/maven-model-3.0.jar from central failed: SSL peer shut down inco
rrectly -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
n project hadoop-maven-plugins: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.a
pache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:maven-plugin:2.7.2: Could not transfer artifac
t org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apach
e.org/maven2): GET request of: org/apache/maven/maven-model/3.0/maven-model-3.0.
jar from central failed
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDe
pendencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:221)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resol
veProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAr
eResolved(MojoExecutor.java:245)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:199)
```

I am using a windows 7 enterprise 64 bit machine and there is no proxy configured in IE. Can somebody help me to resolve this issue?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Using `openssl s_client -connect servername:443` you can debug what protocol the server supports and perform tests by forcing flags like ssl2, ssl2, check [this](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_client.html)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response. However I am not sure why we need to check the protocol here. When I build there are huge set of maven libraries getting downloaded and only this particular one is failing.

Comment: so try to download it without maven and install it manually with the command `mvn install:install -Dfile ....`

Comment: If I am using the openssl command to test the protocol what should be the servername given

Comment: if you're in your own computer : so localhost like this : `openssl s_client -host localhost -port 443`